# Unable to connect python with TWS using ibapi

Tags: interactive-brokers, tws, ib-api

This is my code:

```
from threading import Timer
from ibapi.client import EClient
from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper
from ibapi.contract import Contract
from ibapi.order import *

class TestApp(EWrapper, EClient):

    def __init__(self):
        EClient.__init__(self, self)

    def Error(self, reqID, errorCode, errorString):
        print('Error :', reqID, '', errorCode,'', errorString)

    def contractDetails(self, reqID, contractDetails):
        print('Contract Details :', reqID, '', contractDetails)

    def nextValidId(self, orderId):
        self.nextOrderID = orderId
        self.run()

    def orderStatus(self, orderId, status, filled, remaining, avgFillPrice, permID, lastFillprice, cliendId, whyHeld, mktCapPrice):
        print('Orderstatus Id. ', orderId, 'Status: ', status, 'Filled: ', 'Remaining: ', remaining, 'Last Fill Price: ', lastFillprice)

    def openOrderEnd(self, orderId, contract, order, orderState):
        print('Open Order ID. ', orderId, contract.symbol, contract.secType, '@', contract.exchange, ': ', order.action, order.orderType, order.totalQuantity, orderState.status)

    def execDetails(self, reqId, contract, execution):
        print('Exec Details. ', reqId, contract.symbol, contract.secType, contract.currency, execution.execId, execution.orderId, execution.shares, execution.lastLiquidity)

    def accountSummary(self, reqId, account, tag, value, currency):
        print('Account Summary. ', reqId, account, tag, value, currency)

    def start(self):
        contract = Contract()
        contract.symbol = 'NFLX'
        contract.secType = 'STK'
        contract.exchange = 'SMART'
        contract.currency = 'USD'
        contract.primaryExchange = 'NASDAQ'

        order = Order()
        order.action = 'BUY'
        order.totalQuantity = 2
        order.orderType = 'LMT'
        order.lmtPrice = 539.50

        self.placeOrder(self.nextOrderID, contract, order)

    def stop(self):
        self.done = True
        self.disconnect()


def main():
    app = TestApp()
    app.nextOrderID = 0
    app.connect('127.0.0.1', 7497, 0)

    Timer(3, app.stop).start()
    app.run()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I am just getting the basic messages when I execute this code:

ERROR -1 2104 Market data farm connection is OK:hfarm
ERROR -1 2104 Market data farm connection is OK:usfarm.nj
ERROR -1 2104 Market data farm connection is OK:usfuture
ERROR -1 2104 Market data farm connection is OK:jfarm
ERROR -1 2104 Market data farm connection is OK:eufarm
ERROR -1 2104 Market data farm connection is OK:cashfarm
ERROR -1 2104 Market data farm connection is OK:usfarm
ERROR -1 2106 HMDS data farm connection is OK:euhmds
ERROR -1 2106 HMDS data farm connection is OK:fundfarm
ERROR -1 2106 HMDS data farm connection is OK:ushmds
ERROR -1 2158 Sec-def data farm connection is OK:secdefnj

I copied the code from the IBKR online video. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I would higly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are connected, you just never placed the order in your start method.  Consider renaming your start method since maybe calling Timer.start is confusing.

```
from threading import Timer
from ibapi.client import EClient
from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper
from ibapi.contract import Contract
from ibapi.order import *

class TestApp(EWrapper, EClient):

    def __init__(self):
        EClient.__init__(self, self)
        self.nextOrderID = 0 # if this is init code put it in init

    def Error(self, reqID, errorCode, errorString):
        print('Error :', reqID, '', errorCode,'', errorString)

    def contractDetails(self, reqID, contractDetails):
        print('Contract Details :', reqID, '', contractDetails)

    def nextValidId(self, orderId):
        self.nextOrderID = orderId
        #self.run() you already called app.run
        self.start() # call your start function, you never did so order wasn't placed.
    
    # you missed parentId, just copy these big defs from the source
    def orderStatus(self, orderId, status, filled, remaining, avgFillPrice, permId, parentId, lastFillPrice, clientId, whyHeld, mktCapPrice):
        print('Orderstatus Id. ', orderId, 'Status: ', status, 'Filled: ', 'Remaining: ', remaining, 'Last Fill Price: ', lastFillPrice)
        #maybe disconnect when order is filled
        if remaining == 0.0:
            self.stop()

    def openOrderEnd(self, orderId, contract, order, orderState):
        print('Open Order ID. ', orderId, contract.symbol, contract.secType, '@', contract.exchange, ': ', order.action, order.orderType, order.totalQuantity, orderState.status)

    def execDetails(self, reqId, contract, execution):
        print('Exec Details. ', reqId, contract.symbol, contract.secType, contract.currency, execution.execId, execution.orderId, execution.shares, execution.lastLiquidity)
        
    def accountSummary(self, reqId, account, tag, value, currency):
        print('Account Summary. ', reqId, account, tag, value, currency)

    def start(self):
        contract = Contract()
        contract.symbol = 'NFLX'
        contract.secType = 'STK'
        contract.exchange = 'SMART'
        contract.currency = 'USD'
        #contract.primaryExchange = 'NASDAQ'#??may be ISLAND, but not needed for nflx

        order = Order()
        order.action = 'BUY'
        order.totalQuantity = 2
        order.orderType = 'LMT'
        order.lmtPrice = 539.50
        
        self.placeOrder(self.nextOrderID, contract, order)
        self.nextOrderID +=1 # always increment after use

    def stop(self):
        #self.done = True # unnecessary 
        if self.isConnected() : 
            print("disconnecting")
            self.disconnect()
        
def main():
    app = TestApp()
    app.connect('127.0.0.1', 7497, 123)

    #Timer(3, app.stop).start() #means you want to stop in 3 seconds no matter what
    app.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you for that. However, I am unable to get the function accountSummary and openOrderEnd to run. How can I fix this?

Comment: You don't ask for them.  Check the docs for how to request them.  eg. http://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/account_summary.html#acct_summary_req

Comment: This is function is under the class TestApp

Comment: def accountSummary(self, reqId, account, tag, value, currency):
        self.reqAccountSummary(reqId,account, tag, value )
        print('Account Summary. ', reqId, account, tag, value, currency)

Comment: It still doesn't show that in the python console. How should I fix it?

Comment: You have to reads the docs or ask another question.  A response will come after a request, the docs explain how.

Comment: Sorry to disturb you but I am new to python.

Comment: This function is in the TestApp class

Comment: def accountSummary(self, reqId, account, tag, value, currency):
        self.reqAccountSummary(9002, 'All', '$LEDGER')
        super().accountSummary(reqId, account, tag, value, currency)
        print('Account Summary. ReqID: ',reqId, 'Account: ', account, 'Tag: ', tag, 'Value:', value, 'currency: ', currency)

Comment: that isn't right either and I don't understand where I am going wrong